# Angular unit test cases service method

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Problem:  When i am running unit test case for service file then it is saying that

**'Spec 'MerchantsService getMerchantData' has no expectations.'** instead of showing the console.log, please help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my service file containg

```
  getMerchantData(searchParams: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/merchants-data-url${searchParams}`)
  }
```

and below is the spec file for service.

```
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { MerchantsService } from './merchants.service'
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

describe('MerchantsService', () => {
  let service: MerchantsService

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
    })
    service = TestBed.inject(MerchantsService)
  })

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('getMerchantData', async() => {
    service.getMerchantData('?page=1').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('getMerchantData', res.data)
      expect(res.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test the http calls and make mock responses.

Try this:

```
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { MerchantsService } from './merchants.service'
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing'
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

describe('MerchantsService', () => {
  let service: MerchantsService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
    })
    service = TestBed.inject(MerchantsService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // after each test, verify no outstanding api calls remain
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('getMerchantData', () => {
    const mockMerchantData = {
      data: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }], // mock your response to whatever you want
    };
    service.getMerchantData('?page=1').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('getMerchantData', res.data)
      expect(res.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
    });
    // you have to know your Base URL and put it in the placeholder below
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${BASE_URL_HERE}/merchants-data-url?page=1`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET'); // expect a get request
    req.flush(mockMerchantData); // give this response to the API call in queue
  });
})
```

You should read [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf) article in how to test HTTP calls in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your method 'getMerchantData' is finished before any expectation have been done. Your subscribe callback is not executed at the end of the method.

You should try like this :

```
it('getMerchantData', (done) => {
    service.getMerchantData('?page=1').subscribe((res) => {
       console.log('getMerchantData', res.data)
       expect(res.data.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
       done()
    })
})
```

By the way you will have another problem, you should mock http response as AliF50 said in his response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970121/4923347

You should read how to test asynchronous test :

- https://medium.com/@michaelericksen_12434/angular-asynchronous-test-patterns-and-recipes-202cf7d47ec7
- https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-async-service